# apache tiles put-list-attribute XML error

Tags: list, jakarta-ee, attributes, tiles

I've got such definitions in my tiles.xml:

```
<definition name="t.base" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/base.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="SomeTitle" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="scripts" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/scripts.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="t.homepage" extends="t.base" preparer="com.blogspot.symfonyworld.lyricsbase.controller.TestViewPreparer">
    <put-list-attribute name="body">
        <add-attribute value="/WEB-INF/jsp/homepage.jsp" />
        <add-attribute value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer.jsp" />
    </put-list-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="title" value="lyricsBase : home of lyrics" />
    <put-attribute name="view" value="homepage" cascade="true" />
</definition>
```

The compiler throws me an exception when a request is handled for homepage:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 18; The content of element type "definition" must match "(put-attribute*,put-list-attribute*)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
```

I've got no idea what is wrong - the XML syntax seems to be correct according to the [tiles docs](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/list-attributes.html).

Answer (score 7):

The `<put-list-attribute>` element must be at the end of the definition, as follows:

```
<definition name="t.homepage" extends="t.base" preparer="com.blogspot.symfonyworld.lyricsbase.controller.TestViewPreparer">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="lyricsBase : home of lyrics" />
    <put-attribute name="view" value="homepage" cascade="true" />
    <put-list-attribute name="body">
        <add-attribute value="/WEB-INF/jsp/homepage.jsp" />
        <add-attribute value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer.jsp" />
    </put-list-attribute>
</definition>
```